# Variadic template in mingw-c++

Tags: c++, templates, mingw, variadic

```
#ifndef KGMCALLBACK_H
#define KGMCALLBACK_H

//Class for declare callback func

class kgmObject;

template <class F> class kgmCallback;

template <class F, class... Args>
class kgmCallback<F(Args...)>
{
public:
  typedef F (*Function)(Args...);

private:
  void* object;
  Function   function;

public:
  kgmCallback()
  {
    object = null;
    function = null;
  }

  kgmCallback(void* obj = null, Function fn = null)
  {
    object = obj;
    function = fn;
  }

  F operator()(Args... args)
  {
#ifdef __MINGW32XXX__
    __asm__ volatile
    (
      "mov %eax, %edx\n"
      "mov %eax, %ecx\n"
    );
#endif
    return kgmCallback::function(args...);
  }

  bool hasObject()
  {
    return (object != null);
  }

  bool hasFunction()
  {
    return (function != null);
  }

  void* getObject()
  {
    return object;
  }
};

#endif // KGMCALLBACK_H
```

this correctly work on linux-g++.

in some class
    {
      typedef kgmCallback ClickEventCallback;
      ClickEventCallback callback;

```
}
contructor
{
 callback = kFileDialog::ClickEventCallback(this,        (kFileDialog::ClickEventCallback::Function)&kEditor::open); ...
}
```

when we call and send as first parameter class pointer mapOpen wars fine in linux.
but when I compile code by mingw problem occur. in debugger is visible that first parameter 
is not correct class, instead of it is temporary kgmCallback class pointer.
seems mingw run function(args..) as local function, not static. and set own this as 
first parameter.

had anyone similar problem? or maybe version problem? i use mingw g++ 4.8.1

Comment: What is `null`? `nullptr`?

Answer (score 0):

Check your `function` declaration: **Is not static at all** (It has no sense to be static though). So instead of doing `kmgCallback::function(args...)` do `function(args...)`. Also you forget to pass the `this` pointer of the member function stored in `function`. The correct call should be:

```
(*object).function(args...);
```

But instead of reinventing the wheel, what was not very successful isn't?, use `std::function` and `std::bind`:

```
std::function<R(ARGS...)> callback;
callback = std::bind(&kEditor::open, std::ref(*this) , std::placeholders::_1 , ... );
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to very late answer. Problem was solved. Developer forgot use `__stdcall` while declare callback function.